# GDB Compression Not Updating Base Tables

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, excel, arcgis-10.4, versioning, compression

I'm having an issue when compressing a database the edits are not being posted to the base table immediately, this sometimes takes hours until I can see the edits. Right now the only way I can force the changes to show is shut down the portal service -> compress -> restart the service. Is there another way I can go about doing this so I don't need to shutdown the services to push all edits to the base tables?

For clarification, when I make an edit in portal and exit the edit session I go to compress the database from ArcCatalog. None of these edits show in the base table. If I compress again a few hours later they may or may not show up in the base table.

This is becoming a problem for me when it comes to tracking jobs. I have an excel tracker where I bring in the database table and do vlookups for completion dates. I have a python script that runs every hour to compress the database and thought I could rely on the spreadsheet being updated at the bottom of every hour.

Without shutting down connected services the lowest endstate count I can get is 2 if that matters.

Comment: How many versions still exist when you Compress?

Comment: 1, just the DEFAULT

Comment: What version of ArcGIS?  Have you considered using versioned views for your Excel lookup?  The later versions of ArcGIS create these automatically (I'm unsure which version this started with), and they are great for getting the most up-to-date view of the data from a non-arcgis lookup

Comment: The endstate count is a symptom.  If you do a SQL query on the versions table you may see a version still present - if this outstanding version changes every few hours, this may explain why it can take hours to see those changes

Comment: Sometimes I can only get the endstate to 4 or 3.

Comment: How can I bring in a versioned table into excel instead of the default?

Comment: Look for a view called something like `featclassname_evw` or `featclassname_vw` where `featclassname` is the name of your feature class.  See [What is a versioned view?](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/what-is-a-versioned-view.htm)

Comment: Will I need to continue compressing every hour to see the latest changes if I go about doing it this way?

Comment: It depends on what else you are running on your data.  You should probably still compress daily to keep things tidy, but the versioned view will display all up-to-date features no matter the compress state.  Having things uncompressed for too long can have a performance impact, so a compress is still important.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can get the excel sheet to work the way you describe. As for compression I plan to just change my script to run every day at midnight instead of hourly.

Comment: Remember to also update statistics by running Analyze.  See [Geodatabase maintenance](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-sql-server/overview-maintenance.htm).  If you're not using SQL Server the links on the left should lead you to different RDBMS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53638/discussion-between-ryan-and-midavalo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Midavalo's help I've found a better way of handling this. I should have been connecting to the versioned table view within excel instead of trying to directly connect to the base table. However, for some un-explainable reason I could not see the view ending in .evw for the layer I was interested in. I first tried to enable SQL access via ArcCatalog but would receive and error saying "Creating a view on myDB.DBO.myLayer failed: Attribute Coloumn not found.

To fix this issue I first "unregistered as versioned" the dataset this layer was part of and then "registered as versioned" again. After I've done this the .evw view for the layer I needed was able to be seen.

This is a much better way of bringing the most up to date data into excel. I notice changes as soon as they are made instead of being delayed by hours!