# Geodatabse Compression does not make changes in Base Tables

Tags: arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

This question has been asked here [GDB Compression Not Updating Base Tables](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228410/gdb-compression-not-updating-base-tables), but the solution provided is not what I am looking for.
I have registered a feature class and made some edits in that version, the version is default. I want to sync these changes in base table without unregistering it. I know that compression does not transfer changes if edits are not referenced by all the versions therefore I don't have have any other version than default.
How can I transfer these changes to base map without  unregistering it? Why doesn't compression makes any chages?

Comment: You are mistakenly asserting only one version, since replication requires a version as well. It's quite possible you have a number of versions or even a corrupt version tree. Tech Support would be better able to walk you through repair.

Comment: I have deleted all replicas therefore its associated versions are also deleted. Where can I check the other version, I dont see any in the tree.

Comment: So your enterprise geodatabase install may have been corrupted in the gyrations. This is a Tech Support topic, not something for GIS SE, because it requires too much back-and-forth. There are tons of GeoNet discussions on the topic of *listing* versions, like [this one](https://community.esri.com/thread/210550-is-there-an-esri-way-to-see-if-there-is-versioned-data-still-in-progress-that-needs-compressing)